# Filtering on embedded document with Python Eve Rest and Mongo

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I want to filter something by embedded document's property. But I couldn't achieve this.

```
http://localhost:5000/vehicle?embedded={"model.brand":1}&where={"model.brand":"5bf3f02e63da120b27dc74b1"}
```

Is there any way to make this query? I didn't find any solution to filter by subdocuments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not supported by python eve.

Check out this link: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/python-eve/O4e1GTS3jZs/HSZxcK85BAAJ

Nicola Iarocci himself answers this question with the reason It would be hard to do due to mongo’s lack of native data relations.